# JS: append cannot find attr

Tags: javascript

```
$(".btn").click(function()
{
    $(".content").append(
    "<div class='randomDiv' id='1'></div>"
    );
}
```

If above is "active" then I cannot:

```
$(".randomDiv").click(function()
{
    alert($(this.attr("id")));
}
```

I've googled and found out that it is because JS is loaded before I append, but haven't found a solution how to "register after load" on JS.

Comment: Go read up on _event delegation_.

Comment: That's not the proper way to bind event to dynamic control.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

## Attach the event handler when you create the element

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $("<div class='randomDiv' id='1'></div>")
        .on("click", myFunction)
        .appendTo(".content");
}

function myFunction() {
    alert($(this.attr("id")));
}
```

… so the element *does* exist when you bind the event handler

## Use a delegated handler

```
$(document).on("click", ".randomDiv", function () {
    alert($(this.attr("id")));
});
```

… that captures all the click events as they bubble up the document and checks which elements they came from.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to fetch data from input too? If they're appended?

Answer (score 0):

If you append the element dynamically then the normal click function wont work. Use

```
$(document).on("click",".randomDiv",function(event){
       alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to fetch data from input too? If they're appended?

Comment: $(this).find("input#inputId").val(); or $(this).find("input.inputClass").val()

Comment: There will be no problem in getting the value from input when appended dynamically. you can use $("#inputid").val() to get the input value after appended.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".content").on('click', '.randomDiv', function()
{
    alert($(this.attr("id")));
}
```

$(".content") can be replaced with any existing parent item of randomDiv. Say content div is inside page-left div then above code can be written as

```
$(".page-left").on('click', '.randomDiv', function()
{
    alert($(this.attr("id")));
}
```

Or even

```
$(document).on('click', '.randomDiv', function()
{
    alert($(this.attr("id")));
}
```

which bind event to the document level in DOM

Depending upon the version of jQuery you should use live, delegate, bind or on function.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to fetch data from input too? If they're appended?